No difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, why?
I am trying to sort a sequence of letters using the Order LINQ operator, and I am not getting the expected result. I was expecting that passing the StringComparer.CurrentCulture would produce a different order than passing the StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, but both seem to ignore the case of my letters:
string[] letters = ["y", "X", "Z"];
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", letters.Order(StringComparer.CurrentCulture)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", letters.Order(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));

Output:
X, y, Z
X, y, Z

Online demo.
I was expecting that the CurrentCulture would be sensitive to the case of the letters, and would produce this order: X, Z, y, because the small English letters are farther in the ASCII chart than the capital English letters. What am I not understanding correctly?

Try this one: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SQ0p6q

@Progman Ah, so they are sensitive to each other (x < X, y < Y etc), but not with the other letters?

The difference of StringComparer.CurrentCulture and StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase is relevant when you have two values which have the "same" string/text, but may have different cases. In your example ["y", "X", "Z"] the strings are all "different", as "x" still comes before "y" and "y" still comes before "z". And this has nothing to do with the cases of these strings.
But when the sorting algorithm sees a list like ["x", "X", "X", "x", "x", "X"] there is a difference if the values "x" and "X" should be the same regarding sorting (so the Compare() method returns 0) or if they should be different (so the Compare() method will return -1/1 or any other value smaller/bigger zero).
When you use the following code:
string[] letters = ["y", "X", "Z", "X", "x", "y", "Y", "z", "Z", "y", "Y", "z", "Z"];
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", letters.Order(StringComparer.CurrentCulture)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", letters.Order(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));

you will get the following result:
x, X, X, y, y, y, Y, Y, z, z, Z, Z, Z
X, X, x, y, y, Y, y, Y, Z, z, Z, z, Z

In the second line, all the "same" letters are equal to each other, the case is literally ignored as instructed. And since the sorting algorithm is stable, the relative order of the "same" letters are still in the same original order (here on the letter "y"):
["y", "X", "Z", "X", "x", "y", "Y", "z", "Z", "y", "Y", "z", "Z"]
  ^                        ^    ^              ^    ^
  1                        2    3              4    5

X, X, x, y, y, Y, y, Y, Z, z, Z, z, Z
         ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
         1  2  3  4  5


Thanks, now it makes sense. I was really puzzled when I saw this behavior though.

As far as I understand his happens because those comparers perform Linguistic comparisons:

This linguistic comparison is sometimes referred to as "word sort order."

And you have expected the ordinal one.
From the docs:

You compare strings to answer one of two questions: "Are these two strings equal?" or "In what order should these strings be placed when sorting them?"
Those two questions are complicated by factors that affect string comparisons:

You can choose an ordinal or linguistic comparison.
You can choose if case matters.
You can choose culture-specific comparisons.
Linguistic comparisons are culture and platform-dependent.



The System.StringComparison enumeration fields represent these choices:

CurrentCulture: Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules and the current culture.
CurrentCultureIgnoreCase: Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the current culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.
InvariantCulture: Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules and the invariant culture.
InvariantCultureIgnoreCase: Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the invariant culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.
Ordinal: Compare strings using ordinal (binary) sort rules.
OrdinalIgnoreCase: Compare strings using ordinal (binary) sort rules and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.


Hence switching to the oridnal counterparts:
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", letters.Order(StringComparer.Ordinal)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", letters.Order(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

Will result in the expected output:
X, Z, y
X, y, Z

Demo @sharplab.io

Thanks Guru Stron, your answer is useful too. :-)
